# Consulta MYSQL no resulta

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta mysql.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN s.id='1' THEN r.nombre ELSE 0 END) as sucursal1,
(CASE WHEN s.id='2' THEN r.nombre ELSE 0 END) as sucursal2 
FROM repuestos r INNER JOIN sucursales s on s.id = r.idsucursal WHERE r.codigo_venta=1992
```

y el resultado es.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agregando group by r.codigo_venta me da resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL resultado que quiero obtener es :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito orientación.

Comment: entonces cual es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: edite la pregunta agregando el resultado que quiero obtener.

Comment: Hola, podrías pasar las tablas implicadas sí es posible con los datos ?

Comment: El problema es que cada `id` es una fila, por eso te arroja dos filas. Una forma de resolver esto sería un `GROUP_CONCAT` para traer los dos valores en una sola columna con un separador: `BUJIA Q16_BUJIA Q16V` y luego trabajarlos por código mediante el separador. El `GROUP_CONCAT` debería ir combinado con un `GROUP BY r.codigo_venta`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en realidad cada `id` es una fila distinta, por eso te arroja dos filas. Una forma de resolver esto sería mediante un `GROUP_CONCAT` para cada sucursal, combinado con un `GROUP BY r.codigo_venta`, algo así más o menos:

```
SELECT 
    r.codigo_venta,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN s.id=1 THEN r.nombre ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR '') sucursal1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN s.id=2 THEN r.nombre ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR '') sucursal2      
FROM repuestos r 
    INNER JOIN sucursales s on s.id = r.idsucursal 
    WHERE r.codigo_venta=1992
    GROUP BY r.codigo_venta ;
```

---

#### Prueba de concepto

Aquí te dejo una prueba basada en datos reales, puedes <kbd>**[VER UNA DEMOSTRACIÓN EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/WDMB16202)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sucursales 
(
    id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sucursal      VARCHAR(150),
    CONSTRAINT sucursal_PKA01 UNIQUE (sucursal)
 )ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS repuestos 
(
    id             INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre         VARCHAR(50),
    idsucursal     INT,
    codigo_venta   INT,
    CONSTRAINT repuestos_PKA01 UNIQUE (nombre),
    FOREIGN KEY (idsucursal) REFERENCES sucursales(id) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO sucursales (sucursal) 
    VALUES
    ('Sucursal 1'),
    ('Sucursal 2'),
    ('Sucursal 3');

INSERT INTO repuestos (nombre, idsucursal, codigo_venta) 
    VALUES
    ('Bujía 1', 1, 1992),
    ('Bujía 2', 2, 1992),
    ('Bujía 3', 1, 1993),
    ('Bujía 4', 1, 1994) ;

SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';

SELECT 
    r.codigo_venta,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN s.id=1 THEN r.nombre ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR '') sucursal1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN s.id=2 THEN r.nombre ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR '') sucursal2      
FROM repuestos r 
    INNER JOIN sucursales s on s.id = r.idsucursal 
    WHERE r.codigo_venta=1992
    GROUP BY r.codigo_venta ;
```

---

**Resultado:**

```
codigo_venta    sucursal1      sucursal2
---------------------------------------------
1992            Bujía 1        Bujía 2
```

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias. respuesta clarisima. excelente solución.saludos.

Comment: @JohnL me alegro de que te haya sido útil. Saludos.